# insert an array of images into prompt box in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var input = new Array();
input = ['../color/Red.jpg', '../color/Yellow.jpg','../color/Blue.jpg'];
var choice=prompt("choose four colours from  :    "+input);
</script>
```

i want to display the images in prompt box;

Comment: You can't add images to a native JavaScript prompt.

Answer (score 3):

You can't display images in the `prompt()` box. This only accepts text, no images or HTML.

You could use a custom modal popup instead, for example: [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 2):

The prompt box only accepts text, sorry. You could try putting the images in a div and then styling the div as a popup, though.

Comment: give me the code for putting the images in a div and then styling the div as a popup.